# put pen to paper

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, idioms-in-context

What does "They’ve put pen to paper" exactly refer to in the following news extract? Is it a paraphrase of the preceding "The early parts of the deal have been inked already'?

> They’ve had a deal in place for five years. The early parts of the deal have been inked already. **They’ve put pen to paper**, and this is going to cost the French $65 billion. It’s a huge amount of money, especially relative to the size of the French economy, so that’s why the French are furious.

Comment: You haven't included a source

Comment: I'm surprised you're asking about ***put pen to paper***, but no mention of what looks to me like a much more obscure usage: *[parts of the deal have been] **inked***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To address whether the sentence is a paraphrase of the preceding one, we have to delve into the meaning of "ink."

Comment: @Apollyon: I'm not impressed by the clarity (more accurately, *lack* of clarity) of the text overall anyway. The references to ***inked*** and ***put pen to paper*** seem to be about something relatively recent/current - but this is after we've just been told that the deal has been ***in place for five years***. To my mind that implies *The early parts of the deal **were signed years ago***, which is significantly different to ***have been inked already.*** Whatever the *intended* meaning, the text certainly isn't ***clear / unambiguous*** to *this* native speaker!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "put pen to paper" simply means "to start writing", but the context describes what they are writing.  In this context, we see that "parts of the deal have been inked already", which means that parts of the deal have already been "written down in ink", and not in pencil, which can be erased-- so an inked deal cannot be easily changed.

From this, we can see that "put pen to paper" cannot mean "begin writing the deal", because that has already been written.  What is further to write?  Their signatures.  Signing the contract, with a pen in hand, completes a deal and makes a contract official.

For a dictionary-like reference, see: [Your Idioms](https://www.youridioms.com/en/idiom/put-pen-to-paper)

You'll notice that the second definition of this idiom is explicitly "to sign a contract".

Comment: Assuming "put pen to paper" means "to sign a contract," is it redundant, given the preceding "parts of the deal have been inked already"? To ink a deal is to sign it too.

Comment: "Inked" *can* mean to sign a contract, but it can also mean to *create a final version of the contract (that will be signed soon)*.  I assume this 2nd meaning is being used here, otherwise it would be redundant, as you said.  As I mentioned in my answer, this meaning of "ink" is contrasted with "penciled".  Something that is penciled can easily be changed or erased, something inked cannot.

Comment: The quoted passage is actually from a CNN transcript.  As it is spoken by nature, is  redundancy impossible?

Answer (score 3):

Both phrases are metaphorical, meaning making and/or signing a contract. Someone may have used an actual pen to sign a contract at some point, but it probably exists in digital form with many printed copies, involving more toner than ink.

There was once a time when people had to write and sign things with pen and ink, after they settled the details.

Comment: Is it redundant, since the preceding sentence "The early parts of the deal have been inked already" already conveys the meaning?

Comment: The sense they intended may be that *inked* means settling on terms, and *putting pen to paper* means signing a contract, which wouldn't necessarily be redundant. But setting aside the metaphors, it all adds up to there being an agreement shutting out the French.

Comment: You mean the two metaphors reinforce that meaning?

Comment: No, the metaphors are part of the writer's colorful style. I don't see that they strengthen the meaning.

Comment: Is the "set out terms" reading of "ink" listed in the dictionary?

Comment: Do yo mean "settling on terms"? It's not an idiom, just the usual meanings of the words.